# Entity Framework - restoring navigation property after detaching entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading, objectcontext

My Entity Framework model (using EF 6.1 with ObjectContext), has lazy loading turned on, with various navigation properties.

For example:

```
// Orders is a navigation property (collection), which, when first iterated,
// loads the collection of Order entities from the DB
var orders = Customer.Orders.ToList();
```

In my app, for performance reasons, I want to be able to detach `Order` entities and allow them to be garbage collected:

```
MyContext.Detach(order1);
MyContext.Detach(order2);
MyContext.Detach(order3);
```

But, I have found that when I detach only a subset of the child entities (i.e. not all of them), the next iteration of `Customer.Orders` does not work – the detached entities are not part of the returned collection.

**What code can I write to get the `Customer.Orders` navigation property to restore and work correctly in this situation, forcing it to reload and re-attach all entities, including those previously detached?**

I have tried manually setting `Customer.Orders.IsLoaded` to `false`, but that doesn't work - the entities are not re-loaded, and somewhere under the EF hood `IsLoaded` simply gets set back to `true`.

Comment: I assume .Load() won't work either?

Comment: If you have to detach entities *for performance reasons* I have a feeling that your problem is at a deeper level of your architecture. More specifically: a context that lives too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LoadProperty method:

`context.LoadProperty(customer, c => c.Orders, MergeOption.OverwriteChanges);`

Comment: Awesome, this did exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

to detach entities just use AsNoTracking

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();
}
```

if you want entity framework again to track changes you need Attach it to context and use ctx.myDbSet.Include(x=>x.Something)